# On button click fade in fade out

Tags: javascript, html

i have button `<input type="submit" id="btnApply" name="btnApply" value="Apply"/>`

when button click it show a div

```
<div>
Thanks for apply
</div>
```

should be fade in

after 5 seconds it should fade out

Comment: After submitting the form ?

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: yes submitting form @Rayon

Comment: Is this an assignment for us?

Comment: i tried but i cant do fade in and fade out in single click @DivyeshSavaliya

Comment: don't misunderstand me @NaveenChandraTiwari

Comment: @Rakyir you should search it.you can find lot of tutorials examples on internet

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3XwZv/57/

Comment: You can use seTimeinterval with fadeIn.

Comment: Searched alot but not get proper solution so only posted here @FastSnail

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya thanks for doing my assignments

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you need to use JQuery, Mention some ID to your div as `<div id="div1" >`. With Jquery it's pretty simple:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("#div1").fadeIn(2000);
            $('#div1').delay(3000).fadeOut(2000)
        });
    });
    </script>
```

In above code, when button is clicked div1 is fade in with 2 seconds and after 3 seconds delay it will fade out in 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

check the animation css properties.when button clicked show the div and apply the animation css.
check the animation-fill-mode css property. You can use the value of both.
specify the 0% as opacity 0, 50% as opacity 1 and back to 100% at opacity 0.
Use a animation-duration property and set it to 5 seconds.
Try something along the above lines..

Pankaj